# sql - select records between datetime start and stop and after stop

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this:

```
id timestart            timestop 
1  2014-5-5 23:15:00    2014-5-5 23:17:00
2  2014-5-5 23:30:00    2014-5-5 23:45:00
3  2014-5-5 23:50:00    2014-5-5 23:55:00
4  2014-5-5 23:57:00    2014-5-6 00:05:00
```

I have select statement which returns records between timestart and timestop:

```
select *
from table
where ( timestart >= @start and timestop <= @stop)
```

If @start = '2014-5-5 23:00:00' and @stop = '2014-5-5 23:59:00', select will return first three rows. 
How should I rewrite the select statement to also retrieve row with id=4 (records that have @start after timestart and @stop after timestop?

With this statement I get what I want, but I am not sure this is the best approach:

```
... where 
    (timestart  >= @start and timestart <= @stop) and (timestop <= @stop or timestop >= @stop)
```

Comment: HINT: Where (Existing condition) OR (New condition)

Comment: `(timestop <= @stop or timestop >= @stop)` will be true for each parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your second query you can easily deduce

```
where (timestart >= @start and timestart <= @stop)
```

or even

```
where (timestart BETWEEN @start and @stop)
```

This is because the second part of your statement

```
where (timestart >= @start and timestart <= @stop) 
and (timestop <= @stop or timestop >= @stop) <---this will be true for all timestop entries
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
where timestart BETWEEN ISNULL(@start,timestart) and ISNULL(@stop,timestart)
```